# Win 7 Privilege Level (Run as administrator) via GP or command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line-interface, group-policy, permissions, uac

Is there a way to set the Privilege Level for legacy software via group policy or on the command line?

I have some legacy software, which we unfortunately cannot move away from.  This software requires administrator access.  I know I can go into the Properties dialog and check "Run this program as an administrator" on every single instance on every single one of my workstations, but that gets old after the 30th install.

If I had my way, we would dump this software, find some software that did what we needed, was fully compliant with Win7 security best-practices and give everyone limited user accounts...

However, I am not the boss, so everyone gets administrator accounts.  Given that, I suppose I could just tell everyone to open the context menu and choose "Run as administrator", but we have some very, very, **VERY** low-tech users, and half of them might just choose "Delete" instead.

Anyone know of a way to set this option on the command line? or better yet, through Group Policy?

Comment: Are you sure that running it as administrator is technically required?  Frequently you just modifing the filesystem and registry permissions is enough to get an application to work.

Comment: I've fixed quite a few older applications by using "Application Shims" to make them believe they are running with administrative privileges, while sandboxing their registry and file system access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past I have used a command line utility called [Elevate](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2007/03/27/elevate-a-process-at-the-command-line-in-vista.aspx) to do this by calling it from the application's shortcut and changing the icon to that of the application. You could push this out with the install or via Group Policy?

Comment: That will be perfect.  I can push this out to all users.  Thanks for the tip.